# Ambigious reference to member in Swift 2

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to create a generic Network Operation class to handle the communication to my server. I tested a few things and the error must be the `responseArray`function. But I don't know where?

```
    class NetworkOperation<T> {
        let requestType: NSMutableURLRequest
        var arrayItems: Array<T>?

        typealias JSONDictionaryCompletion = ([String:AnyObject]?) -> Void
        typealias ObjectArrayCompletion = (Response<[T], NSError>) -> Void

        init(requestType: NSMutableURLRequest, arrayItems: Array<T>) {
            self.requestType = requestType
            self.arrayItems = arrayItems
        }

        func downloadJSONFromURL(completion: JSONDictionaryCompletion) {

        }

        func downloadObjectsFromURL(completion: ObjectArrayCompletion) {
            Alamofire.request(requestType).responseArray { (response) in
                if let httpResponse = response, let statusCode = httpResponse.response {
                    switch(statusCode) {
                    case 200:
                        print("OK")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

extension Alamofire.Request {
    // responseObject<...>(...) declares a new .responseX handling function on Alamofire.Request. It uses the responseSerializer as a custom serializer.
    // The <T> means this is a genertic method: it can work with different types of objects. These types must implement the ResponseJSONObjectSerializable protocol.
    // This is needed to guarantee that any type of object that will be passed in will have an init function that takes JSON. The response function takes a single
    // argument called completionHandler. This is the method being called when done parsing the JSON and creating the object to be called async.
    // The completion handler has a single argument Response<T, NSError>. The response object packs up the Result along iwth all the other info from the transaction.
    // The responseObject function returns an Alamofire.Request object

    public func responseObject<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {

        // Create the response serilaizer that will work with the generic T type and an NSError. It will take in the results of the URL Request (request, response, data, error)
        // and use the Result type defined by Alamofire to return success with the object or failure with an error. The responseObject just returns the responseserializer that gets created
        // and allows passing the completion handler where it needs to go.

        let serializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { (request, response, data, error) in

            // Checks that it has valid data using guard. Then it turns the data into JSON and parses it using SwiftyJSON.
            // Then it creates a new copy of the type of class.

            guard error == nil else {
                return .Failure(error!)
            }

            guard let responseData = data else {
                let failureReason = "Object could not be serialized because input data was nil."
                let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                return .Failure(error)
            }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)
                // Get Data content of JSON
                let jsonData = json["data"]

                if let object = T(json: jsonData) {
                    return .Success(object)
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "Object could not be created from JSON."
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }
        return response(responseSerializer: serializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    // Iterate through the elements in the json and create object out of each one and add it to the objects array.

    public func responseArray<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<[T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let serializer = ResponseSerializer<[T], NSError> { request, response, data, error in

            guard error == nil else {
                return .Failure(error!)
            }

            guard let responseData = data else {
                let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
                let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                return .Failure(error)
            }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

            switch result {

            case .Success(let value):
                let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)

                // Get Data content of JSON
                let jsonData = json["data"]

                var objects: [T] = []
                for (_, item) in jsonData {
                    if let object = T(json: item) {
                        objects.append(object)
                    }
                }
                return .Success(objects)

            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }
        return response(responseSerializer: serializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

But when I want to check the status code in the `downloadObjectsFromURL` function, I get the compiler error message:

> Ambigious Reference to member 'request(*:*:parameters:encoding:headers:)'

Where does this error come from. Did I unwrap the optionals in a wrong way?

**UPDATE**

I tested this:

```
func createObjectsFromJSON(completion: ObjectArrayCompletion) {
    Alamofire.request(requestType).responseArray { (response: Response<[AED], NSError>) -> Void in
        print("OK")
    }
}
```

`AED` is a custom class I created. No error message anymore. When I switch `AED` to `T` this error pops up

```
func createObjectsFromJSON(completion: ObjectArrayCompletion) {
    Alamofire.request(requestType).responseArray { (response: Response<[T], NSError>) -> Void in
        print("OK")
    }
}
```

> expected argument type Response<[_], NSError> -> Void

Comment: It's a the error says, not method `Alamofire.request(: NSMutableURLRequest)` seems to exist in the API. Quickly looking over [the Alamofire source](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift), the closes I can find is `public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible)`.

Comment: but even if I change this, I get the same error

Comment: It starts complaining about the request reference as soon as I add the call to reponseArray()

Comment: Hi Matt. I think I do not get it completly, maybe to late at night already. Can you give me a hint how to do it please?

Comment: Where exactly did Matt's answer go...

Comment: You've solved the problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: Actually not :) I want to keep the function generic. If I would do [AED] I always will create response arrays that contain AED objects. But I want to keep it open which type by defining the type in the signature

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "keep the function generic". You _must_ resolve the placeholder. You can't reuse the placeholder name like that. You must _resolve_ T in your call.

Comment: Ok.. I understand that.. But is there a way that I can pass the class name I want to resolve in the call in the function signature that encompasses this call?